# Which part of the Temple did they recite prayers?

Tags: tefilla, beis-hamikdash, korban, smell

It is forbidden to pray in the presence of excrement. (See [here](http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1170785/jewish/The-Proper-Environment-for-Prayer.htm) for one source.)

Numerous animals were brought for sacrifices in the Temple (Bet Hamikdash.) Prior to slaughter, some animal probably excreted, or smelled from excrement, I assume. Prayers were also recited in the Temple.

Did they recite these prayers in a separate time and / or separate area as the sacrifices themselves or in an area far away from the animal smell? How were the prayers done in the Temple in a way that did not conflict with the aforementioned halacha?

Comment: (Supporting your idea that animals probably defected is the fact that for that reason the animal had its rear end away from the altar during slaughter.)

Comment: The same issue applies to any blessing in a slaughterhouse, not just the temple. See ShA YD 19:1

Comment: @msh210 Can you provide a source for that? And why should the animals' rear ends point away from the altar versus the heichal or another part of the temple?

Comment: @HaLailahHaZeh that its rear end was away from the altar is in _mishnayos Tamid_, at the beginning of chapter 4, and the reason I mention is in commentaries thereon. As to *why* it should point away from the altar as opposed to anywhere else, I don't know. Maybe commentaries there discuss that also. [You can ask, of course.](/questions/ask)